# Copy dropdownlist from another list with DataTextField and DataValueField

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I create one datalayer method

```
  public static List<SegmentBL> GetAllSegment(string SortDirection, string SortExpression)
    {

        var ds = DBHelper.GetDatabase().ExecuteDataSet("UDS_Select_SegmentMaster");

        var val = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(r => new SegmentBL
        {
            _SegmentId = Convert.ToInt32(r[0].ToString()),
            _SegmentName = r[1].ToString()
        });
        List<SegmentBL> list = val.ToList();
        return list;
    }
```

from that I create one Bussiness logic method

```
public DropDownList GetAll(string SortDirection, string SortExpression)
    {
        var list = new DropDownList();
        list.DataSource = SegmentDL.GetAllSegment(SortDirection, SortExpression);
        list.DataTextField = "_SegmentName";
        list.DataValueField = "_SegmentID";
        list.DataBind();
        ListItem item = new ListItem();
        item.Text = "--Select--";
        item.Value = "0";
        list.Items.Insert(0, item);
        return list;
    }
```

Finally Presentation Layer Method for filling dropdownlist

```
 private void FillSegment()
    {
        ddlSegment.DataSource = seg.GetAll(General.SortAscending,"SegmentID").Items;

        ddlSegment.DataBind();
        ddlSegment.DataTextField = "_SegmentName";
        ddlSegment.DataValueField = "_SegmentID";
    }
```

It's working fine except the DataTextField and DataValueField not assign properly. Currently DataTextField and DataValueField same. What is mistake I did in above code.

Comment: not sure the business logic should be creating UI elements - can you just return the datasource items to the presentation layer. It doesn't seem logical to try and bind the same thing twice.

Comment: Because same line of code I used in my application more then 20times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding before the elements are added to the datasource bind after the elements being added. You may `pass` dropdownlist to your method intead of creating local drop down in `GetAll` method.

```
public DropDownList GetAll(string SortDirection, string SortExpression, DropDownList list)
{
  //  var list = new DropDownList(); //Remove this line
    list.DataSource = SegmentDL.GetAllSegment(SortDirection, SortExpression);
    list.DataTextField = "_SegmentName";
    list.DataValueField = "_SegmentID";      
    ListItem item = new ListItem();
    item.Text = "--Select--";
    item.Value = "0";
    list.Items.Insert(0, item);
    list.DataBind();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Hey I need to pass there ref DropDownList List as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Move the Databind() line.

```
private void FillSegment()
    {
        ddlSegment.DataSource = seg.GetAll(General.SortAscending,"SegmentID").Items;


        ddlSegment.DataTextField = "_SegmentName";
        ddlSegment.DataValueField = "_SegmentID";

        ddlSegment.DataBind(); //After and not before defining the fields value
    }
```